# Entity Framework error in converting float to double

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4

I have a stored procedure which returns data in a form of the following table

```
ID int null,
RestaurentName varchar(250),
Address nvarchar(150),
Area nvarchar(150),
City nvarchar(50),
Postcode nvarchar(50),
DeliveryPrice decimal(4,2),
DeliveryTime nvarchar(50),
Latitude nvarchar(50),
Longitude nvarchar(50),
LogoLocation nvarchar(50),
Rating float,// returns AVG of rating
Discount money
```

I did a function import in my EF.
Now when I run the site, i have the following error

> The 'Rating' property on 'SearchRestaurantByKey_Result' could not be
>   set to a 'Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null
>   value of type 'Decimal'.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this??

**EDIT:**
This is where I am having the error:

```
var query = (from p in dc.GetRestaurantByAreaAndCategory(area,type)
                         select new RestaurantViewModel()
                         {
                             Name = p.RestaurentName,
                             Address = p.Address,
                             City = p.City,
                             Postcode = p.Postcode,
                             ID = Convert.ToInt32(p.ID),
                             LogoPath = p.LogoLocation,
                             DeliveryPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(p.DeliveryPrice),
                             DeliveryTime = p.DeliveryTime,
                             discount = p.Discount,
                             Rating=Convert.ToDouble(p.Rating) //here is the error.

                         }).ToList();
```

In the RestaurantViewModel(), the rating property is Double.

Comment: Check the Rating property on your entity - isn't it by chance of decimal type? Also, you need provide more data - like your entity definition and a relevant edmx fragment. In essence the exception is saying that EF read a value double type from the database but the property it was trying to set the value to is of decimal type which is an invalid operation.

Comment: No the Rating property on the entity is Double. I have added some more info, let me know if you need some more.

Comment: The exception probably already occurs in `GetRestaurantByAreaAndCategory` (it says `SearchRestaurantByKey_Result`).